# I am not sure on this error within google sheets script editor

Tags: google-sheets

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  ui.createMenu('Useful Information')
      .addItem('How do I Book?', 'menuItem1')
      .addSeparator()
      .addItem('Where do I Screenshot?', 'menuItem2')
      .addSeperator()
      .addItem('How do I Book?', 'menuItem1')
      .addSeparator()
}

function menuItem1() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setHeight('60').setWidth('150');
  app.setTitle("Here is a helpful link to the guide");
  var panel = app.createPopupPanel()
  var link = app.createAnchor('Click here! :D','http://prntscr.com/eg5x59');
  panel.add(link);
  app.add(panel);
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  doc.show(app);
}

function menuItem2() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setHeight('60').setWidth('150');
  app.setTitle("Here is a link to the radio");
  var panel = app.createPopupPanel()
  var link = app.createAnchor('Screenshot the red box using Lightshot','http://habboun.com/radio');
  panel.add(link);
  app.add(panel);
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  doc.show(app);
}

function menuItem3() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setHeight('80').setWidth('150');
  app.setTitle("Here is a link to the DOR page");
  var panel = app.createPopupPanel()
  var link = app.createAnchor('Post your Screenshot here on the most recent   Special Task. Format is dd/mm/yy - HH:MM-HH:MM', 'http://habboun.com/content/department-radio');
  panel.add(link);
  app.add(panel);
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  doc.show(app);
}
```

So i am receiving this error http://prntscr.com/eg9ftl
and i have no clue how to fix it. Please help me. I have looked through different forums and everything but yet i cannot find a solution because most solutions are to specific projects.

Comment: Also, note that UiApp has been deprecated and should not be used..

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/ui-app

Answer (score 0):

The error you show is

```
TypeError: Cannot find function addSeperator in object Menu.
```

"addSeperator" is spelling mistake. Please change from addSeperator to addSeparator. And also "addToUi" is necessary for your `onOpen()`. So your script of `onOpen()` is

From :

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  ui.createMenu('Useful Information')
      .addItem('How do I Book?', 'menuItem1')
      .addSeparator()
      .addItem('Where do I Screenshot?', 'menuItem2')
      .addSeperator()
      .addItem('How do I Book?', 'menuItem1')
      .addSeparator()
}
```

To :

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  ui.createMenu('Useful Information')
      .addItem('How do I Book?', 'menuItem1')
      .addSeparator()
      .addItem('Where do I Screenshot?', 'menuItem2')
      .addSeparator()
      .addItem('How do I Book?', 'menuItem1')
      .addSeparator()
      .addToUi();
}
```